# As a US citizen, how can I establish Portugal residency without losing my German visa?

Tags: visa, citizenship, eu-citizens

I am an US citizen currently working in Germany on a Blue Card. I wish to establish residency in Portugal to eventually attain dual US-Portuguese citizenship.  I know that having 2 EU long-term visas simultaneous is not allowed, and that you will lose either visa without residing there for atleast 6 months each year. Is there anyway  this be done without giving up my German visa?

Or would it possible to de-register in Germany, establish residency in Portugal then work for German companies in Portugal with a Portugal D7 visa?

Comment: "I know that having 2 EU long-term visas simultaneous is not allowed": What is your source for that information? I don't think it's correct.